# Finding the list of people in a distribution list (contact list) using graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, outlook.com

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the list of people in a distribution list (contact list) in Outlook.com using the Microsoft Graph API.

So far I was able to retrieve the distribution group name etc.. using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$search=DL_NAME
```

I'm certain that it's what I'm looking for because the result from API includes the following

```js
"personType": {
  "class": "Group",
  "subclass": "PersonalDistributionList"
}
```

This is weird anyways, because it shows up using `people` endpoint and not the `contacts`.

What I need from this point on is to be able to retrieve the list of people in the distribution list. I've tried querying using the id in the result but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things...

1. DLs are actually represented by the `group` entity in Microsoft Graph, so in your case you should be able to use the `id` returned from your people search in the following to get the group/DLs members

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members`

2. You could just search for your DL by filtering on the `group` entity:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=displayName eq 'DL_NAME'`

3. The `people` API (see this [topic](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/social_overview)) is really about people that you communicate with most often - and it includes users, groups and contacts.

Hope this helps,

Comment: also to add, the Group API entity permission scope is 'high-privilege',  requiring admin consent in an organization